# XSLT contains two periods

Tags: xslt, xpath, contains

I have an HTML document that used an unordered list to display the navigation. When it is output as XML it no longer uses the list, but instead assigns each link a `<Description>`. The way that the description works is that the main links are assigned numbers like 100, 200, 300, 400, and so on. Subnavigation links from those are assigned as follows: 200.100, 200.200, 200.300, and so on.

The XML looks like the following:

```
<Items>
  <PgIndexElementItem>
      <Description>100</Description>
      <Title>This is the Title</Title>
  </PgIndexElementItem>
  <PgIndexElementItem>
      <Description>200</Description>
      <Title>This is the Title</Title>
  </PgIndexElementItem>
  <PgIndexElementItem>
      <Description>200.100</Description>
      <Title>This is the Title</Title>
  </PgIndexElementItem>
  <PgIndexElementItem>
      <Description>200.100.100</Description>
      <Title>This is the Title</Title>
  </PgIndexElementItem>
</Items>
```

If you look at the last PgIndexElementItem, there are three sets of numbers.

I'm trying to recreate the unordered list using XSLT. This is what I have been doing so far:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="//PgIndexElementItem">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(Description, '.'))">
            <li><a href="{ResolvedURL/ServerRelative}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//PgIndexElementItem">
                        <xsl:if test="contains(Description, '.')">
                            <li><a href="{ResolvedURL/ServerRelative}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a></li>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

My question would be, is there a way to specify a `contains(Description` that targets descriptions with two periods, like the last PgIndexElementItem above?

I hope I explained this well enough. I don't know how to make it less confusing. Thanks in advance!

EDIT

```
o Graduate Program
   * How to Apply
   * Masters Program
        o M.A. Handbook
        o FAQs
        o Alumni
        o Masters Theses
        o Sample Thesis Proposals
   * M.A. Handbook
   * FAQs
   * Alumni
   * Masters Theses
   * Sample Thesis Proposals
```

Comment: does your parser support xpath 2 or xslt 2?

Comment: Not sure. How would I find that out? Sorry, whole new world with this stuff.

Comment: @jrottier, what technology you run this code from ?

Comment: Your XML needs a single top-level element, a parent of the PgIndexElementItem elements. E.g. surround the whole thing with `<root>`...`</root>`.

Comment: There is an `<Items>` element that surrounds all of the PgIndexElementItem elements. There are quite a few more above that as well, but I didn't list them for simplicity.

Comment: I'm really puzzled though as to why you would want `<xsl:for-each select="//PgIndexElementItem">` inside another `<xsl:for-each select="//PgIndexElementItem">`.

Comment: I tried it without the second `for-each` and I didn't get any results. When I added it I got an output of all links with a `<Description>` that contained a period, so that's why I kept it.

Comment: @jrottier: ok, I think I understand better. I will add something to my answer to suggest another way to do this...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple, generic one-liner XPath expression, solution that can detect any desired number of dots. :) –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:if test="contains(substring-after(Description, '.'), '.')">
    ...
```

to test whether an element has a Description child with two or more periods.

However, I would instead change your XSLT to:

```
  <!-- this part replaces your <ul> code above -->
  <ul>
     <xsl:apply-templates
         select="//PgIndexElementItem[not(contains(Description, '.'))]" />
  </ul>
```

**Updated this template:**

```
<!-- add this new template -->
<xsl:template match="PgIndexElementItem">
   <li>
      <a href="{ResolvedURL/ServerRelative}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a>
      <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="concat(Description, '.')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="childOptions"
         select="../PgIndexElementItem[starts-with(Description, $prefix)
           and not(contains(substring-after(Description, $prefix), '.'))]"/>
      <xsl:if test="$childOptions">
         <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$childOptions" />
         </ul>
      </xsl:if>
   </li>
</xsl:template>
```

This will avoid unnecessary code duplication, and unwanted empty `<ul>` elements.

I've made some assumptions about how the Description children are to be interpreted... e.g. "200.100" should appear in a sublist under "200" but not under "100".

Comment: @jrottier - I added a big suggestion regarding XSLT a few seconds after your comment.

Comment: Wow! That's great! Works almost perfectly! I tested it out on a few pages! The only problem is that some of the elements repeat when they shouldn't. I added an example to my question above.

Comment: @jrottier: can you tell us which elements repeat when they shouldn't? and make sure your sample XML includes those elements, everywhere that they appear... and their parent menu items.

Comment: @jrottier: also, can we assume that in your input XML, the menu items appear in the same order you want them to appear in the output? E.g. "200" always appears before "200.*"?

Comment: @LarsH The problem only occurs when it is a third level navigation element. If you look at the XML example I posted in the question the very last PgIndexElementInfo is where the problem occurs. And I do have a page with a fourth level nav element that causes the same problem. So the two instances where it happens would be elements like: 400.300.200.100 and 400.300.100. Does that help?

Comment: @LarsH Yes, it is in the right order. The only time I have seen it out of order is when it gets to 1000, which then displays after 100 but before 200, but other than that it is in the right order.

Comment: @jrottier: see my answer, where I added the $prefix variable and modified the $childOptions variable select. It had been recursing on descendant menu items instead of just child ones.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
string-length(Description) - string-length(translate(Description, '.',''))  = 2
```

**This works the same for any number `$n`** (while the "substring-after" technique is simply unusable in the general case):

```
string-length(Description) - string-length(translate(Description, '.',''))  = $n
```

Comment: +1 clever... I was looking for something like this using translate(), but couldn't get it right.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, `translate()` is one of the most versatile XPath functions.

Comment: Also: `string-length(translate(Description,translate(Description,'.',''),''))`

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but these are too-many `translate()`s :) Probably my answer is slightly more efficient.

Comment: Yes. The outer most `translate()` would make the expression to reach the exponential complexity, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're dealing with nested `PgIndexElementItem` elements - if they nest in multiple layers you should consider refactoring your XSL to use a recursive template (assuming the HTML output for each level is predictable).

As it is written, your for-each loop selects all the PgIndexElementItem descendants of the current element, then does that *again* when it hits the inner for-each loop.  Possibly not what you intended.

Comment: "all the PgIndexElementItem descendants of the current element" - actually, all the PgIndexElementItem descendants of the root node (/). The current node is not taken into account; that would be ".//PgIndexElementItem". But I agree about the refactoring...